# mvc4 web api - treating uint/int/enum as long, float/double as double

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a task of creating RESTfull Services using ASP.NET MVC4 Web API. One of the Service Method is looking like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage TagAdd([FromBody] Tag tag)
{
   HttpResponseMessage result;
   Tag tmpTag = new Tag();
   tmpTag.Name = tag.Name;
   tmpTag.DataType = tag.DataType;
 }
```

**Here Tag looking like this:**

```
public class Tag : Dictionary<Tag.Property, object>
{
public enum Property : int
{
    Name = 0,
    DataType
}
public enum NativeDataType : int
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Scaled,
    Float,
}
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        object value;
        return TryGetValue(Property.Name, out value) ? (string)value : null;
    }
    set
    {
        this[Property.Name] = value;
    }
}
public NativeDataType DataType
{
    get
    {
        object value;
        return TryGetValue(Property.DataType, out value) ? (NativeDataType)(value) : NativeDataType.Undefined;
    }
    set
    {
        this[Property.DataType] = value;
    }
}
```

}

**Here Current issue is**, the enum NativeDataType is treating as long when i sent below JSON request:
{"Name":"ABCD","DataType":2}

unfortunately, Tag class was defined in another assembly. Because of that

tmpTag.DataType = tag.DataType; statement leading to exception(invalid cast) because of cross boundary issue.

1. How can is fix this issue?
2. Why enum was treating as long? even i observed uint, int, long, enum were treating as long and float, double were treating as double on call stack.
3. i can get exact value like below

   object value = null;
   tag.TryGetValue(Tag.Property.DataType, out value);
   tmpTag.DataType = Convert.ToInt32(value);

but, rather accessing one by one Tag elements and convert them to exact type, is there any easiest way to automatically convert and sent to another assembly?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting it can you just do a simple cast? Also Inheriting from int should default to INT32 but for some reason your getting int64 (long). Try inheriting from int32 explicitly.